# Find if a view is laid out

Tags: android

Is there a backwards compatible way to find out if a view is laid out? `View` has [`isLaidOut`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isLaidOut()), but it's API 19. I currently use `if(view.getWidth() + view.getHeight() > 0)`, but it doesn't look like a stable and clean way to do this. I'm aware of `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, but I want to know if a view is laid out right now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This also had me stumped for a while.

If you're using the support-v4 libraries, then you can use:

```
ViewCompat.isLaidOut(View)
```

Check out the implementation:

[ViewCompat.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/70acb0c/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.java#929)

[ViewCompatBase.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f91071f/v4/donut/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompatBase.java#49)

Comment: The implementation is nearly identical to mine pre-kitkat. `view.getWidth() > 0 && view.getHeight() > 0`. I guess this is the closest I'll get to a solution without using a listener to set a flag.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Fixed the busted link, @Elisa.